# Using django template tags with JavaScript

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I use Django's template tags within JavaScript? This is my code:

```
{% block scripts %}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var classEditor = {
            dcg: $("div.control-group"),

            set: function(i, errors) {
                $dcg = $(classEditor.dcg[i]);
                $dcg.addClass("error");
                $dcg.children('div').children('div').children('p').text(errors);
            }
        };

        {% if form.email.errors %}
            {% for err in form.email.errors %}
                {{ e|add:err }}
            {% endfor %}
            classEditor.set(1, {{ e }});
        {% endif %}
    })
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

I want to send all errors to a function and do something with it. I tried to use `striptags` and `stringformat`, but it always raises errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your problem has to anything to do with Javascript. The issue is here:

```
{{ e|add:err }}
```

This makes no sense at all. It seems like you're trying to build up a list, `e`, consisting of all the items in `form.email.errors`. But you can't do that sort of thing in a template - no data manipulation is allowed, by design. The `add` filter simply performs numeric calculations for display, it doesn't modify objects.

You probably want to serialize the errors to JSON in your view, and pass that JSON object to `classEditor.set`.